# JavaScript Ambiguity between (1) and 1

Tags: javascript, javascript-engine, expression-evaluation

What is difference between (1) and 1.

```
1.toString() //Will throw error
1.toFixed(1) //Will throw error
(1).toString() // output "1"
(1).toFixed(1) // output 1.0
```

Answer (score 6):

The trailing period on `1.` is part of the number -- the compiler reads it as a decimal point, not as the dot operator. This makes an identifier immediately following the number unexpected.

Consider, for comparison: `1.0toString()`

Comment: I don’t think anyone would expect `1.0toString()` to work, however `1.0.toString()` works fine.

Comment: I think @duskwuff meant to say `1.0.toString()` ?

Comment: @AnthonyC I mean what I said, and I said what I meant. :)

Comment: @duskwuff was supplying `1.0toString()` as something that is obviously even to human eyes an error - and that is parsed exactly the same as `1.toString()` by the Javascript compiler.

Comment: @duskwuff I understood `1.` explanation but what does (1) mean to compiler?

Comment: @JagajitPrusty what do you suppose that `(1) + 1` means? Do you understand what `( )` means in ordinary algebra?